# Calculating mean and Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am stuck on this question from a tutorial sheet I am going through.

Compute the mean and Gaussian curvature of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is given by

$z=f(x)+g(y)$

for some good functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$.

I tried calculating the first and second fundamental forms to then find $\kappa=\dfrac{det II}{det I}$ but it seems long and I feel like there should be an easier way. Also that doesn't tell me the mean curvature.

Comment: It is a slightly tedious calculation, yes. The mean curvature is the trace of the 2nd fundamental form.

Comment: @Tomas The mean curvature is the trace of the Weingarten map, to be more precise

Comment: @YuriVyatkin yes, you are right.

Answer (score 11):

Let us first recall some definitions and useful formulas for a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by an immersion $F\colon U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set.

Denote $F_x = \frac{\partial F}{\partial{x}}$, $F_{x x} = \frac{\partial{F_x}}{\partial{x}}$, and so on.

The components of the first fundamental form are $I_{x x} = F_x \cdot F_x$, $I_{y y}=F_y \cdot F_y$, $I_{x y} = I_{y x} = F_x \cdot F_y$

For the second fundamental form we may use the expression for the unit normal vector
$$
n = \frac{F_x \times F_y}{|F_x \times F_y|}
$$
so that $II_{x x} = n \cdot F_{x x}$, $II_{y y} = n \cdot F_{y y}$,  $II_{x y} = II_{y x} = n \cdot F_{x y}$

The  Gaussian curvature $K(x,y)$ has the following expression
$$
K(x,y) = \frac{II_{x x} II_{y y} - II_{x y}^2}{I_{x x} I_{y y} - I_{x y}^2} \tag{1}
$$
and the mean curvature can be computed by
$$
H(x,y) = \frac{I_{x x} II_{y y} - 2 I_{x y} II_{x y} + I_{y y} II_{x x}}{I_{x x} I_{y y } - I_{x y}^2} \tag{2}
$$
In the proposed problem we a given a surface represented by a graph of function $z = f(x) + g(y)$, so our immersion has the following form:
$$
F(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
x  \\
y  \\
f(x) + g(y) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and we calculate $F_x = \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 0  \\ f' \end{pmatrix}$,  $F_y = \begin{pmatrix} 0  \\ 1  \\ g' \end{pmatrix}$,  $F_{x x} = \begin{pmatrix} 0  \\ 0  \\ f'' \end{pmatrix}$, $F_{y y} = \begin{pmatrix} 0  \\ 0  \\ g'' \end{pmatrix}$, $F_{x y} = \begin{pmatrix} 0  \\ 0  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

This is enough to find the unit normal
$$
n = \frac{(f', -g', 1)^T}{\sqrt{1 + (f')^2 + (g')^2}}
$$
so we find the components of the second fundamental form $II_{x x} = \frac{f''}{\sqrt{1 + (f')^2 + (g')^2}}$, $II_{y y} = \frac{g''}{\sqrt{1 + (f')^2 + (g')^2}}$, $II_{x y} = 0$

The components of the first fundamental form are, of course, $I_{x x} = 1 + (f')^2$, $I_{y y} = 1 + (g')^2$, and $I_{x y} = f'g'$.

I would let you to finish the job by substituting these quantities into equations (1) and (2).

Comment: I think this is the correct formula for the mean curvature: $H(x,y) = \frac{I_{x x} II_{y y} - 2 I_{x y} II_{x y} + I_{y y} II_{x x}}{2(I_{x x} I_{y y } - I_{x y}^2)}$

Comment: @hugh_maths It depends on the convention. see. e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature). But I agree, that your formula is used more frequently. Nevertheless, it is only a scale factor. Use it to your taste!

Comment: oh, I did not know that. Thank you!