# Problem about finding Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

The problem is about Gaussian Curvature
When we define $M=r(u,v)$ be the surface parametrized by $(u,v)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $N$ be a unit normal vector of $M$. In my lecture we denote Gaussian curvature $\kappa=\det(B)/\det(A)$ where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
<r_u,r_u>&&<r_u,r_v>\\
<r_v,r_u>&&<r_v,r_v>
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}
<N_u,r_u>&&<N_u,r_v>\\
<N_v,r_u>&&<N_v,r_v>
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then show that

1. $N_u,N_v$ can be written as linear combination of $r_u,r_v$
2. if $(N_u,N_v)=(r_u,r_v)\begin{pmatrix}
   a&&b \\
   c&&d
   \end{pmatrix}$ show that $\kappa=\det\begin{pmatrix}
   a&&b \\
   c&&d
   \end{pmatrix}$

I found some useful answers in [Calculating mean and Gaussian curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135305/calculating-mean-and-gaussian-curvature) and now try to solve the problem here but somehow still cannot solve it. Let 
$$M=r(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\r(u,v)\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ then }\quad r_u=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\r_u\end{pmatrix},\quad r_v=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\r_v\end{pmatrix}.$$ 
Therefore 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1+r_u^2&& r_ur_v\\r_vr_u&&1+r_v^2\end{pmatrix}$$ 
but when calculated unit normal vector I got 
$$N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_u^2+r_v^2+1}}\begin{pmatrix}-r_u\\-r_v\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ so 
$$N_u=\frac{1}{(r_u^2+r_v^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}r_u(r_{uu}+r_{uv})-r_{uu}\\r_v(r_{uu}+r_{uv})-r_{uv}\\-r_{uu}-r_{uv}\end{pmatrix},\qquad N_v=\frac{1}{(r_u^2+r_v^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}r_u(r_{vv}+r_{uv})-r_{uv}\\r_v(r_{vv}+r_{uv})-r_{vv}\\-r_{vv}-r_{uv}\end{pmatrix}$$ but I still cannot express $N_u,N_v$ in term of $r_u,r_v$ and find the $\kappa$. Did I misunderstand or miscalculate something?

Comment: You seem to be considering the graph of a function $r : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ - are you sure this is the intended meaning? Your opening description sounds more like a direct parametrisation $r : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ to me.